# printing duplicate of last two number of fibonacci

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I am trying to print Fibonacci numbers up to n.  The code below prints outs the last number twice for some reason, please help.

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  let i;
  const fib = [];

  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;

  for (i=2; i<n; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
    fib.push(fib[i]);
  }
  console.log( fib );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign either the value at the index **or** push the sum.

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
    let i;
    const fib = [];

    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;

    for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1]; // either this assignm. or the next line only
        // fib.push(fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1]);
    }
    return fib;
}

console.log(fibonacci(8));
```

Comment: thanks, but i realise now the code won't work for n=1

Comment: @MaxES, it depends, whaich style you prefer. according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), you could add a check and set the first values as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  let i;
  const fib = [];

  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;

  for (i=2; i<n; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
    // Remove the following line as you are already assigning the value in the line above.
    //fib.push(fib[i]);
  }
  console.log( fib );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove

```
fib.push(fib[i]);
```

Then

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    let i;
    const fib = [];

    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;


    for (i=2; i<n; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
    }
}

fibonacci(7);
```

give output:

```
[ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
```

## Update

After comment I fixed code to make possible usage of it for `i=1`

```
"use strict";

function fibonacci(n) {
    let i;
    const fib = [];

    fib[0] = 0;

    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        fib[i] = ((fib[i-2]!==undefined)?fib[i-2]:1) + fib[i-1];
    }
    console.log(fib)
}

fibonacci(1);
fibonacci(2);
fibonacci(7);

[ 0 ]
[ 0, 1 ]
[ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
```

I removed definition of `fib[1]`, and in sum giving `i` element use value `1` for them only when `fib[i-2]` is `undefinted` it means that this condition is satisfied only when `i=1`, because loop start from `1` but table `fib` do not have key `-1`. When `i` is greater than `1`, then `fib[i-2]` exists and equation has values as earlier.

Comment: thanks, but i have realised that the code does not work for n=1

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong: you first create the nth element in the array and then you push the same element in the array, duplicating it. You don't need the push command.

Correct code would be:

```js
    function fibonacci(n) {
      let i;
      const fib = [];
    
      fib[0] = 0;
      fib[1] = 1;
    
      for (i=2; i<n; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
      }
      console.log( fib );
    }
    fibonacci(5);
```